# Is the splitting field of $x^7+x^5+x^2+1$ over the field $F$ with 25 elements a separable extension?

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, roots, splitting-field, separable-extension

Is the splitting field of $x^7+x^5+x^2+1$ over the field $F$ with 25 elements a separable extension?

I know that $F\simeq \mathbb{Z}_{25}$. I found the roots in $\mathbb{Z}_{25}$ with a calculator: $4,7,9,14,19,24.$

I know it looks like I'm just asking for the answer, but I'm just learning separable extensions, and yet everything seems very awkward to me. What can I do to see if this extension is separable? Does exists any method, like step-by-step?

Comment: $\Bbb Z_{25}$ is not the field with $25$ elements. It's not a field.

Comment: What is your definition of a separable extension?  What theorems about them have you learned so far that you can use?  (Some such theorems would make this problem completely trivial--for instance, that any algebraic extension of a finite field is separable.)

Comment: $x^7+x^5+x^2+1=(x^2+1)(x^5+1)=(x^2 + 1) (x + 1) (x^4 - x^3 + x^2 - x + 1)$

Comment: Is your characterization of "separable polynomial, $p$" one which has $\deg(p)$ pairwise distinct roots in its splitting field over the base field?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner also $x^2+1=(x+2)(x+3)$ in $\mathbb F_{25}.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field $\Bbb F_{25}$ with $25$ elements is a quadratic extension of $\Bbb F_5=\Bbb Z_5$. As such, any factoring of a polynomial over $\Bbb F_5$ is valid also over $\Bbb F_{25}$. And over $\Bbb F_5$ we have
$$
x^7+x^5+x^2+1=(x^2+1)(x^5+1)\\
=(x^2-4)(x+1)^5=(x+2)(x-2)(x+1)^5
$$
Which is to say the polynomial splits completely over $\Bbb F_5$ and therefore also over $\Bbb F_{25}$. And it is not difficult to see that $\Bbb F_{25}/\Bbb F_{25}$ is a separable extension.

Comment: I know that some $f$ is separable over $F$ iff all roots of $f$ have multiplicity one. How can I get there knowing that $f$ splits completely over $F$?

Comment: @Robson We aren't trying to show that some polynomial is separable. We are trying to show that some _extension_ is separable. Specifically, the smallest extension needed for $f$ to split completely. In this case, the extension in question is the trivial one (i.e. not really extending anything), and it is easy to see that any trivial extension is separable.